# C: Function received strings seem to always have 4 spaces

Tags: c, string, function, parameter-passing

As I was practicing the use of fgets() to read string from input, I found myself copying the same piece of code over and over, so I created a function to call every time I need to do it. Here is a simple example of how it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void GetLine(char str[]) {
    // This is the function, I added a printf() to better show what's happening
    printf("Maximum size of the string in GetLine: %i\n", sizeof(str));
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    // This is for clearing the newline character
    // either from the recently received string or from the input buffer
    if (str[strlen(str)-1] == '\n')
        str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
    else {
        char DISCARD;
        while((DISCARD = getchar())!='\n' && DISCARD != EOF);
    }
}

int main() {
    char MyString[51];

    printf("Maximum size of the string in main: %i\n", sizeof(MyString));
    GetLine(MyString);

    printf("Contents of the string: >%s<\n", MyString);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Maximum size of the string in main: 51
Maximum size of the string in GetLine: 4
My name is Pedro
Contents of the string: >My <
```

Notice how `str[]` only have 4 spaces, instead of being the size of the string passed to it.

The workaround for this is pretty easy: make `GetLine()` also receive an integer that holds the size of the string, so it can read the correct number of characters without depending of `sizeof(str)`.

However I'd really like to know both why this happens(the 4 space thing) and if I can fix this method somehow(make `char str[]` the same size as the string passed as argument).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sizeof(str)` in this context `str` is a pointer.

Comment: people have not pointed this out. On your machine a pointer is 4 bytes long (32 bit). So `sizeof(str)` always return 4

Comment: The `sizeof` operator returns the size of a *type*. It's not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);` is incorrect in function `GetLine` as the array is passed as a pointer to its first element. Hence `str` in `GetLine()` is a pointer, so `sizeof(str)` is not the size of the destination array, but merely the size of a pointer, 4 bytes on your system.

You should instead pass the size of the array to `GetLine()` and use that as the size argument to `fgets()`.

There are other problems in your code:

- you should test the return value of `fgets()` to properly detect end of file.
- you should make `DISCARD` an `int` so it can store `EOF` properly.
- you discard the newline from the end of the buffer with an inefficient and slightly incorrect method: there is a remote possibility that `strlen(str)` be `0`.  You could use this one liner:

  ```
  str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';  // discard the newline if present.
  ```

  Or you could use `strchr()`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *GetLine(char str[], int size) {
    if (fgets(str, size, stdin)) {
        char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
        if (p != NULL) {
            // This is for clearing the newline character
            *p = '\0';
        } else {
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                continue;
        }
        return str;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    char MyString[51];

    printf("Maximum size of the string in main: %i\n", (int)sizeof(MyString) - 1);
    if (GetLine(MyString, sizeof(MyString)))
        printf("Contents of the string: >%s<\n", MyString);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: or better - have getline allocate a buffer and return it

Comment: by the way, "Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.", so `strchr()` could be remove just use the return value of `fgets()`.

Comment: @Stargateur: the `GetLine()` function reads a line into the destination array, and strips the newline. Long lines are truncated and the remaining characters are discarded, unlike `fgets()` which breaks long lines and returns the next fragment at the following call.

Comment: @chqrlie I didn't well understand what you said but whatever never mind, I forget that `fgets()` don't return the number of characters read.